# Same module required, different path, variables not shared

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, require

I'm really lost about how `require` works and I try to find the truth.
Nodejs documentation said that each time you require the same module (different path or not) you will get the same object. But for me this isn't the same object even if I require the same module.

I have created a simple project to try this, a memory caching system. First we have the main file, first test file to add an item and second test file to get the added item.

```
//main.js
var exports = module.exports = {};

var debug = require("debug")("memcache:main");

var CACHE = {};

debug(CACHE);

exports.set = addItem;
exports.get = getItem;

function addItem(key, value) {
  debug(key);
  debug(value);

  CACHE[ key ] = value;

  debug(CACHE[ key ]);
  }
}

function getItem(key) {
  debug(key);
  debug(CACHE[ key ]);

  return CACHE[ key ];
}
```

The first test file to add an item

```
//test/test1.js
var memcache = require("../main");

memcache.set("id1", { name: "lola" });
```

The second test file to retrieve the added item

```
// test/child/test2.js
var memcache = require("../../main");

setInterval(
  function () {
    console.log(memcache.get("id1"));
  },
  3000
);
```

And now this is the console outputs

```
MacBook-Pro:memcache fluxb0x$ DEBUG=memcache:* node test/test1.js
  memcache:main {} +0ms
  memcache:main id1 +3ms
  memcache:main { name: 'lola' } +0ms
  memcache:main undefined +1ms
  memcache:main { name: 'lola' } +0ms

MacBook-Pro:memcache fluxb0x$ DEBUG=memcache:* node test/child/test2.js
  memcache:main {} +0ms
  memcache:main id1 +3s
  memcache:main undefined +0ms
undefined
  memcache:main id1 +3s
  memcache:main undefined +0ms
undefined
  memcache:main id1 +3s
  memcache:main undefined +1ms
undefined
  memcache:main id1 +3s
  memcache:main undefined +0ms
undefined
  memcache:main id1 +3s
  memcache:main undefined +0ms
undefined
  memcache:main id1 +3s
  memcache:main undefined +0ms
undefined
```

Any suggestion how can I require the same module with different path, and still have the same variable ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cache is not real memcache, its just an object holding the values. So its not persistent across two executions of node. This can be proved by doing small change to your code.

Change test 2 file to expose a test method

```
// test/child/test2.js
var memcache = require("../../main");

exports.test = function(){
   setInterval(
      function () {
        console.log(memcache.get("id1"));
      },
      3000
    );
}
```

Use exposed test method in test1 after adding the value to cache.

```
//test/test1.js
var memcache = require("../main");
var test2 = require("./child/test2");

memcache.set("id1", { name: "lola" });
test2.test();
```

Then run test1 like you do.

`$ DEBUG=memcache:* node test/test1.js`

This will give you expected results.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now why I couldn't get the object value. My real problem is that I have my application that use my `CacheManager` and a script that run each day to update 2 keys values with new data. I think that is not clean to add a function in the script to get the same object instance. Any solution for this ?

Comment: I'm using `node-cache` for my cache manager `var NodeCache = require("node-cache"); var myCache = new NodeCache()`, and I export the cache through `module.exports = myCache;` in both application and script I require the CacheManager module `var CacheManager = require("../../lib/cache_manager");` and `var CacheManager = require("../app/lib/cache_manager");`.

Comment: Can you post a separate question with all the details and relevant code.

Comment: Sorry to post again but I don't have the edit access available. Here is the link to the [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942058/sharing-a-cache-object-between-my-application-and-a-script)