# Sharing a cache object between my application and a script

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching

I'm trying to share an object (cache object) between my application and a script with no success. The script is executed each day to retrieve some data and update the cache object. After the application use this updated shared object.

This the code of my script executed each day

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var async  = require("async"),
    _      = require("lodash"),
    moment = require("moment"),
    clone  = require("clone");

var StoresManager = require("../app/lib/stores_manager"),
    Logger        = require("../app/lib/logger"),
    TRAKT         = require("../app/lib/trakt"),
    CacheManager  = require("../app/lib/cache_manager");

var WEB_LISTS    = [],
    MOBILE_LISTS = [];

async.waterfall(
  [
    ...,
    function (next) {
      CacheManager.clear(function (err) { next(err); });
    },
    function (next) {
      CacheManager.set("extended_web_browsing_list", WEB_LISTS, function (err) { next(err); });
    },
    function (next) {
      CacheManager.set("extended_mobile_browsing_list", MOBILE_LISTS, function (err) { next(err); });
    }
  ],
  function (err) {
    if ( err )
      throw err;

    Logger.info("DONE!");

    process.exit(0);
  }
);
```

My cache manager module

```
var NodeCache = require("node-cache");

var myCache = new NodeCache();

module.exports = myCache;
```

And the API endpoint that use the cache when needed. When the script is executed and after a request is made the cache object is empty.

```
...
var CacheManager   = require("../../lib/cache_manager");
...

function retrieveWebBrowsingList(extended, response) {
  var data = [];

  async.waterfall(
    [
      function (next) {
        if ( !extended )
          return next();

        Logger.debug(extended);

        CacheManager.get("extended_web_browsing_list", function (err, value) {
          Logger.debug(value);

          if ( !value )
            return next();

          data = value;

          next(true);
        });
      },
      ...
    ],
    function (err) {
      if ( err && typeof err !== "boolean" )
        return Utils.handleError(err, response);

      response.statusCode = httpStatus.OK;
      response.data       = data;

      Logger.debug(response);

      response.send();
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: what is the exact problem you are facing. What are your expectation and observations. Do you get any errors? Please add more info.

Comment: I want a script to be executed each day to retrieve updated data from an API and update the cache using the `CacheManager`. Then when a user make a request to my API, I want the endpoint to return the same updated data from the `CacheManager`. I have no errors. I don't get the cached response data back.

Comment: Where does this cache-manager stores the data? Can you share cache manager details if its open source.

Comment: Yes. This is the github : https://github.com/tcs-de/nodecache